# Parse.com query findInBackground doesn't return any data

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

the function i have below should return all of the students from parse.com, at one section of code (commented below) the list is fully populated with the correct results however at the end of the function the list is empty. I can't quite understand what is happening here, any help is greatly appreciated.

```
public List<Student> getAllStudents() {
    final List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Student");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for (ParseObject o : list) {
                    Student s = new Student();
                    s.setObjectId(o.getObjectId());
                    s.setFirstName(o.getString("FirstName"));
                    s.setSurname(o.getString("Surname"));
                    s.setDOB(o.getString("DOB"));
                    s.setInstructor(o.getBoolean("Instructor"));
                    studentList.add(s);
                }
                // studentList is full here
            } else {

            }
            // studentList is full here too
        }

    });
    // studentList is empty here
    return studentList;
}
```

Comment: try declaring the `studentList` as a global variable.

Comment: @Lal I have tried this however `studentList` is still empty once the code has finished executing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html#findInBackground(com.parse.FindCallback) : public void findInBackground(FindCallback callback)
 
Retrieves a list of ParseObjects that satisfy this **query from the server in a background thread**. This is preferable to using **find()**, unless your code is already running in a background thread.
So if you want result in your method use find or add some notification when FindCallback did his work.

Answer (score 2):

findInBackground and any other background calls are performed on a different background thread, and your completion handler (done) is just a function stored in memory until the background thread finishes processing and calls done. So, when you call getAllStudents, it will

1. create a query
2. tell the query to findInBackground in a different thread
3. step to the line return studentList immediately
4. return to calling function

Whatever you need to do with studentList must be performed in the else {} block, and it will be asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with the above, in plain english, your code will be executed like this:

1. final List studentList = new ArrayList();
2. ParseQuery query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Student");
   ------> 1. query.findInBackground (Popped onto background thread)
3. return studentList (so yes, by the time you get here, studentList will probably be null).

Just remember ".findinbackground" will always go to a background thread.